# Firebase multi location update best practice(samples included) ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im pretty new to Firebase and as i can see their features im loving it so far. I plan to continue using it on the future, but i want to use the best practices possible so I am trying to make a multi location update in Firebase,
I made it working in two ways, but i want to make sure which one is the right way, best way and i want to know why.

First way:

```
NSDictionary *childUpdates = @{
                                       [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/",IDMAllIDMsPathFIR] stringByAppendingString:key]:idmData,
                                       [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@/%@/", IDMUserIDMsPathFIR,self.currentFirebaseUserId, key]: idmData
                                       };
        [self.databaseReference updateChildValues:childUpdates];
```

and the second way is this:

```
  FIRDatabaseReference * allIDMsRef = [[self.databaseReference child:IDMAllIDMsPathFIR] child:key];
    FIRDatabaseReference * userIDMsRef = [[[self.databaseReference child:IDMUserIDMsPathFIR] child:self.currentFirebaseUserId] child:key];

    [userIDMsRef updateChildValues:idmData];
    [allIDMsRef updateChildValues:idmData];
```

**self.databaseReference is the root Reference of Firebase Database**

Please let me know which one is better and why it is better, i would really appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just say that the first approach is better. Everything is explained very clearly [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html).

Comment: Thanks you man, i hope someone will explain it deeper, otherwise i will just accept your answer and go on using this first approach.